# Why am I getting NoMethodError in this code in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, debugging, nomethoderror

So,my question was, Why am I getting `NoMethodError` regarding `sort` method in function `next_bigger` when being called ?

Here's the code :

```
class String
    def sort
        self.chars.sort.join
    end
end

def next_bigger n
    s = n.to_s
    return -1 if n <= 10 || s == s.sort.reverse #This line resulting NoMethodError
    (2..n).each do |p|
        x = (s[0...-(p)] +  s[-(p)..-1].sort).to_i
        return x if x > n
    end
    -1
end

p next_bigger 12
```

Comment: When you report an exception in an SO question please give the precise error message and line of code in which it occurred. Here your error message would have been, `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sort' for nil:NilClass
<main>:10:in 'block in next_bigger'`. The block that begins on line 10 is `each`'s block. The message tells you that `sort`'s receiver, `s[-(p)..-1]`, does not have a method `sort`. You therefore want to look at `s[-(p)..-1]` for different values of `p`. See @slim's answer for that. Incidentally, you can write that `s[-p..-1]`, and for recent versions of Ruby, `s[-p..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not getting the NoMethodError on the line you think you are. It's happening 2 lines later. The other place where you call sort.

```
x = (s[0...-(p)] +  s[-(p)..-1].sort).to_i
```

If you index a range of a string outside it's bounds, you get `nil`

```
""[1..-1] #=> nil
```

You get NoMethodError because you're calling sort on that `nil`.